# How to disable UpdateProgress(on master page) for certain Pages?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, updatepanel, updateprogress

I have this code on Master Page:

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
</asp:ScriptManager>
<asp:UpdateProgress ID="updateProgress" runat="server">
    <ProgressTemplate>
        <div id="aspProgressDiv" style="position: fixed; text-align: center; height: 100%; width: 100%; top: 0;
            right: 0; left: 0; z-index: 9999999; background-color: #000000; opacity: 0.7;">
            <asp:Image ID="imgUpdateProgress" runat="server" ImageUrl="Images/ajax-loader.gif"
                AlternateText="Loading ..." ToolTip="Loading ..." Style="padding: 10px; position: fixed;
                top: 45%; left: 50%;" />
        </div>
    </ProgressTemplate>
</asp:UpdateProgress>
```

And on one of the pages I have a timer which triggers the event automatically and refreshes the page.

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="updatePage" runat="server" >
    <ContentTemplate>
        <asp:Timer ID="timerRefresh" runat="server" OnTick="timerRefresh_Tick" Enabled="true" Interval="10000"></asp:Timer>
        <asp:CheckBox runat="server" ID="chkAutoRefresh" OnCheckedChanged="chkAutoRefresh_CheckedChanged" CssClass="pull-right text-primary" AutoPostBack="true" Text="Auto refresh" Checked="True" />
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

And in C# I have:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {            
            if (!Page.IsPostBack)
            {
                timerRefresh_Tick(null, null);
            }

    }
    catch (Exception exception)
    {
    }

}
protected void chkAutoRefresh_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        timerRefresh.Enabled = chkAutoRefresh.Checked;
    }
    catch (Exception exception)
    {

    }
}

protected void timerRefresh_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        //post data to page
    }
    catch (Exception exception)
    {
       //Do something
    }
}
```

I want that on this page the updateprogress should not work and should work on all pages for all async events.
can I impose a condition like:

```
if(pageName=="abc.aspx"){
   //dont show progressbar
}
```

Or any other alternative?

Answer (score 0):

You can try adding a dummy update panel in your master page like so:

```
<asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" ID="upDummy"></asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Then in your content page load event, associate the `UpdateProgress` to the dummy update panel, like so:

```
CType(Me.Master.FindControl("UpdateProgress1"), UpdateProgress).AssociatedUpdatePanelID =
    CType(Me.Master.FindControl("upDummy"), UpdatePanel).ID
```